# How to solve NPM issue needing multiple versions of same dependency?

Tags: laravel, npm, dependencies, laravel-nova

I am trying to build a Laravel Nova tool, but when I try to install the dependencies for the tool, I get an error. After some time of trying to resolve, it leads back to webpack needing multiple versions for different dependencies, but I can't seem to get it all to work together. In my project folder, when I run `npm audit fix`, I get this error:

```
npm WARN webpack-cli@3.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@^4.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

up to date in 6.37s
fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 15833 scanned packages
1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
```

I can fix this by changing webpack version to the latest version, but then `npm run watch` does not work, and the Laravel Nova tools assets still do not compile correctly.

Here is the error I get when trying to create a nova tool:

```
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
....
 The `/mnt/c/Users/me/projects/project/nova-components/Anothertool/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
 ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed
 ℹ compiling from source
 ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
 ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
at Promise.all.then.arr (/mnt/c/Users/me/projects/project/nova-components/Anothertool/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This problem has been bugging me for a few days now, and no matter what I do or change, I have not been able to solve the issue. I keep getting different errors when installing different versions of packages. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried running it fresh like so:

```
// within your project root directory
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Run each line separately.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this multiple times with different webpack versions in my `package.json` file, no luck. This is part of the error I get when running `npm install`, `/node_modules/pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
  ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed`

Comment: @hoolakoola Have you tried looking into that for some of the answers here? https://github.com/imagemin/pngquant-bin/issues/78

Comment: Ahhhh finally! Thank you - had to patch together a couple of the solutions but got it working.

Comment: @hoolakoola Great! Happy to help. Please accept the answer.